# Spring cloud config security

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I made a classic authorization is spring cloud config server like this:

```
http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).permitAll();
```

Now i try to access props from my client-side app with password and username and its not working. Is there a way to connect using this type of security or should it be basic?

The error looks like this:

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
```

It is not reproducing if I turnning back authorization on server

Answer (score 1):

What error you receive? Can you added to your question?

You need to define a Bean also like in this example:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService users() {
UserDetails user = User.builder()
    .username("user")
    .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$GRLdNijSQMUvl/au9ofL.eDwmoohzzS7.rmNSJZ.0FxO/BTk76klW")
    .roles("USER")
    .build();
UserDetails admin = User.builder()
    .username("admin")
    .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$GRLdNijSQMUvl/au9ofL.eDwmoohzzS7.rmNSJZ.0FxO/BTk76klW")
    .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
    .build();
return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
}
```

Did you try to make an http REST call?
In the error looks like the response it's from Environment type.
Why do you need to access props like that?

Take a look here [Spring boot cloud config client not picking up cloud config with error message: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304948/spring-boot-cloud-config-client-not-picking-up-cloud-config-with-error-message)

This could help you solving the issue.